# Inventory Script (RPG) in C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

I would prefer if more experienced users could give pointers on how I can optimize and think better when writing code.

If you are unfamiliar with unity3d, ignore the use of UnityEngine, the heritage from `MonoBehaviour` as well as the `Debug.Log();`, `Debug.LogWarning();`, and `Debug.LogError();`.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Party : MonoBehaviour {

    private ItemSlot[] inventory;

    public const int INVENTORY_SIZE = 50;

    public Party () {
        ItemSlot[] inventory = new ItemSlot[INVENTORY_SIZE];
    }

    // add q item
    // returns if there was space in inventory or not
    public bool AddItem (Item item, int q) {

        // checks if the item already exist in inventory
        // adding to its stack
        for (int i = 0; i < INVENTORY_SIZE; i++) {
            if (inventory[i].item == item && inventory[i].item.MaxQuantity > inventory[i].quantity) {

                // if whole item fits
                if (q + inventory[i].quantity <= inventory[i].item.MaxQuantity) {
                    Debug.Log ("Added to existing item in one stack " + q + "x " + item.Name);
                    inventory[i].quantity += q;
                    return true;

                // need more slots than 1
                } else {
                    int spotsLeft = (inventory[i].item.MaxQuantity - inventory[i].quantity);
                    Debug.Log("Added " + spotsLeft + "x " + item.Name + " at itemslot #" + i + " - " + q + " left.");
                    q -= spotsLeft;
                    inventory[i].quantity += spotsLeft;

                    // no more items to add
                    if (q == 0) {
                        Debug.Log ("Added (by stacking) " + q + "x " + item.Name);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // still have items left in stack, add to a new slot
        for (int i = 0; i < INVENTORY_SIZE; i++) {
            if (inventory[i].item == null) {
                Debug.Log ("Added " + q + "x " + item.Name);
                inventory[i] = new ItemSlot (item, q);
                return true;
            }
        }

        Debug.LogWarning ("Inventory full! " + q + "x " + item.Name + " left.");
        return false;
    }

    public void Move (int src, int dst) {
        Item tItem = inventory[dst].item;
        int tQ = inventory [dst].quantity;

        inventory [dst].item = inventory [src].item;
        inventory [dst].quantity = inventory [src].quantity;

        inventory [src].item = tItem;
        inventory [src].quantity = tQ;
    }

    // remove q items at i
    // check when calling function to make sure q is greater than or equal to ItemSlot[i].quanity
    public void RemoveItem (int i, int q) {

        // remove q items at i
        Debug.Log ("Removed " + q + "x " + inventory[i].item.Name);
        inventory [i].quantity -= q;

        // removed all? delete item at i
        if (inventory [i].quantity <= 0) {
            Debug.Log ("Deleted " + inventory[i].item.Name);
            DeleteItem (i);
        }

        // error, too many removed
        if (inventory [i].quantity < 0) {
            Debug.LogError ("Quantity at index " + i + " is " + inventory[i].quantity + "!");
            inventory [i].quantity = 0;
        }

    }

    // item at i has a q of 0, delete item
    private void DeleteItem (int i) {
        inventory [i].item = null;
    }
}

// inventory
class ItemSlot {
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;

    public ItemSlot (Item i, int q) {
        item = i;
        quantity = q;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts of what I can improve? Or does it look decent?

I don't need a perfect answer written on a level that I don't understand. I merely want pointers of what to think about. I also welcome material to read about common mistakes.

My current class Item

```
class item {

    string _name;
    int _maxQuantity;

    public item () {
        string _name = string.Empty;
        int _maxQuantity = 0;
    }

    public string Name {
        get {return _name;}
        set {_name = value;}
    }

    public string MaxQuantity {
        get {return _maxQuantity ;}
        set {_maxQuantity = value;}
    }
}
```

It will later hold more information such as description, type (consumable, weapon) and a list of modifying stats (classes storing what stat and how much the weapon increase/decrease).

Comment: could you please provide class item as well?

Comment: For now it only holds setters and getters, such as name, maxQuantity among others.

Comment: I asked because i see no reason of why quantity isn't in item... I also asked myself if maxQuantity shouldn't be in ItemSlot, but I don't know what you're trying try achieve nor your domain logic.

Comment: Have you actually tried this code? It can't work, it has to throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Quantity is in itemslot, it stores how many you currently have of item x. maxQuantity is the stack size of items. I dont know what domain logic is.

Comment: I have not implemented it yet. It only gives a null reference warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. I don't see a reason for why you didn't include a quantity property in your `Item` class. Depending on this you could also treat `Item` as the same as `ItemSlot` so you could get rid of one of those classes. That being said I will review the code without that property in `Item` to be more similar to yours. I also think that you made a mistake in your Constructor. You probably would want to write:

```
public Party () {
    inventory = new ItemSlot[INVENTORY_SIZE];
}
```

I also see no reason for why you shouldn't use `inventory.Length` instead of the constant so I replaced the code that makes use of that constant. Intro being made here follows the alterations that I would make:

Move `Add` and `Remove` logic of a `ItemSlot` to your `ItemSlot` class. I did as follows:

```
class ItemSlot {
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;

    public ItemSlot (Item i, int q) {
        item = i;
        quantity = q;
    }

    //returns the quatity left to add
    public int Add(Item item, int q){
        if (q + quantity <= item.MaxQuantity) {
            Debug.Log ("Added to existing item in one stack " + q + "x " + item.Name);
            quantity += q;
            return 0;
            // need more slots than 1
        } else {
            int spotsLeft = item.MaxQuantity - quantity;
            Debug.Log("Added " + spotsLeft + "x " + item.Name + " - " + q + " left.");
            q -= spotsLeft;
            quantity += spotsLeft;

            // no more items to add
            if (q == 0) {
                Debug.Log ("Added (by stacking) " + q + "x " + item.Name);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return q;
    }

    public bool Remove(int q){
        if(quantity > q){
            quantity -= q;
            Debug.Log ("Removed " + q + "x " + item.Name)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This change makes you have the code in the right place and results on having a "cleaner" `AddItem` algorithm:

```
private int FirstFreeSlot(){
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.Length; ++i){
        if(inventory[i] == null)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

public bool AddItem (Item item, int q) {
    // checks if the item already exist in inventory
    // adding to its stack      
    int idxFree = FirstFreeSlot();
    //you have to iterate the whole array since you can remove any position and you do not shift the elements
    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Length; i++) {
        if (inventory[i].item == item && inventory[i].item.MaxQuantity > inventory[i].quantity) {
            int remain = inventory[i].Add(item, q);
            if(remain == 0) return true;
            if(remain > 0 && idxFree >= 0){
                Debug.Log ("Added " + remain + "x " + item.Name);
                inventory[idxFree] = new ItemSlot(item, remain);
                return true;
            }
            Debug.LogWarning ("Inventory full! " + q + "x " + item.Name + " left.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    //the item wasn't in inventory
    if(idxFree >= 0){
        inventory[idxFree] = new ItemSlot(item, q);
        return true;
    }
    Debug.LogWarning ("Inventory full! " + q + "x " + item.Name + " left.");
    return false;
}
```

This would also imply changes to the `RemoveItem` algorithm:

```
public void RemoveItem (int i, int q) {
    if(!inventory[i].Remove(q)){
        Debug.LogError ("Quantity at index " + i + " is " + inventory[i].quantity + "!");
        inventory [i].quantity = 0;
    }
    // removed all? delete item at i
    if (inventory [i].quantity <= 0) {
        Debug.Log ("Deleted " + inventory[i].item.Name);
        DeleteItem (i);
    }

}
```

I don't see a reason of why you don't simply swap the ItemSlots in your Move code:

```
public void Move (int src, int dst) {
    Itemslot aux = inventory[src];
    inventory[src] = inventory[dst];
    inventory[dst] = aux;
}
```

Comment: The constructor has a fault yes, copy paste failed me.

Inventory should store 50 items instead? Why haven't I thought of that? Thank you. Looks wonderful.

Comment: the size of the array may be a number passed on the constructor for example. You are welcomed to use List<ItemSlot> instead so your inventory may increase dynamically.

Comment: It shouldn't be constant it should be the party members*50, however as I haven't really implemented party members yet I will wait with it. Will update the main post soon with my changes, I am also changing it to store Item instead of ItemSlot.

Comment: @Emz Now than an answer is accepted it may be better to start a new question: otherwise you invalidate existing answers. See for example http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-deal-with-follow-up-questions In future please don't post code for review until after you have run it.

Comment: @Emz The reason for ItemSlot separate from Item is so that the same Item can exist in multiple ItemSlot, with a different quantity in each ItemSlot (quantity is a property of ItemSlot not of Item).

Answer (score 1):

Why use `inventory[i].item` every time? For performance cache this:

```
var x = inventory[i].item;
```

Comment: C# compiler may be able to make those type of replacements. But it is a good suggestion however. It suits more as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: @BrunoCosta I'm not sure. If a have a behaviour in Get Method of the inventory[i].item ? Or have a virtual implementation on this property. Don't make sense compiler cache this.

Comment: @AcazSouza I took in account that item is a field, the same would apply if it would be an Auto-Property. But as I stated it is a good suggestion, as you should not rely on compiler.